# PHP ORMs and optimized relationship queries

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, relationships

I need a PHP ORM to work with relations well.
Please consider code below in Zend:

```php
$persons = new Persons();
$person = $persons->find(5)->current();
echo 'Name: '.$person->fullname;

$phones = $person->findDependentRowset('Phones');
foreach($phones as $phone)
    echo 'Phone: '.$phone->phonenumber;
```

Or code below in xPDO:

```php
$person = $xpdo->getObject('Persons', 5);
echo 'Name: '.$person->get('fullname');

$phones = $person->getMany('Phones');
foreach($phones as $phone)
    echo 'Phone: '.$phone->get('phonenumber');
```

in both scripts, ORMs executes two queries as below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id=5;
SELECT * FROM phones WHERE person=5;
```

It means one query for main object and one query for each relation but what i need is using ONE query for main object and its relations!
xPDO can do it as below:

```php
$person = $xpdo->getObjectGraph('Persons', '{"Phones":{}}', 5);
echo 'Name: '.$person->get('fullname');

foreach($person->Phones as $phone)
    echo 'Phone: '.$phone->get('phonenumber');
```

which executes this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM persons
LEFT JOIN phones ON phones.person=persons.id
WHERE persons.id=5
```

This is great but its not possible to set fields to get from tables!
it means in this case xPDO use **"SELECT * "** so if i get an object and its 4 relations, i will get all fields of all these tables!

So i need an ORM to execute query below for example above:

```sql
SELECT persons.fullname , phones.phonenumber FROM persons
LEFT JOIN phones ON phones.person=persons.id
WHERE persons.id=5
```

Doctrine can do it via DQL but i think Doctrine is not good for personal projects. Is there any PHP ORM to do this?

Thanks
AHHP

Comment: What's wrong with Doctrine? You can configure your entities to perform single queries with joins by using "eager fetching". See http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html. Also, `Zend_Db_Table` is **not** an ORM. At best, it's an implementation of the table-data-gateway pattern

Comment: Thanks Phil. Doctorine is heavy for small projects! Would you please give me sample for my example? How to do it with(out) DQL?

Comment: I have no idea what "heavy for small projects" means. It's a tool, you use it. If you want an ORM in your project, Doctrine would be my first choice. Also, see [Eager Loading](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading). You essentially add `fetch="EAGER"` to your association mapping. Also, it's *Doctrine*, not *Doctorine*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xPDO can do it.  You just have to adjust your thinking and your request.

Remember the objectGraph utilizes the class name of the object, where as the relationships in the graph are used in the graph and query.

```
 $criteria = $this->xpdo->newQuery('prefixClient');
            if (!empty($limit))
                $criteria->limit($limit);
            $criteria->where(array('Child.planid' => $this->getPrimaryKey(),
                                   'Child.active' => true,
                                   'GrandChild.someAttribute' => true,
                                   'GreatGrandChild.someOtherAttribute' => true,
                                   'suspended' => false
                             ));

            $out = $this->xpdo->getCollectionGraph('prefixClient', '{"Child":{"GrandChild":{"GreatGrandChild":{}}}}', $criteria);
```

You set the WHERE on any aspect of the relation, including the current object as show in the suspended => false line.

My book might help you a little in establishing your schema and relations.  Objects should always be singular in nomenclature, whereas their relations can be plural (1:M) or singular (1:1).

Answer (score 1):

Oh Man,

I have been eating this dog food for about 2 months, and I love it. RED BEAN.

http://www.redbeanphp.com/

Nested beans, which is their words for having one object as a property of another.

http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual/nested_bean

Whole file is pretty small. Works with SQL. I am using it on a massive project and loving how quickly I can get things done.

John.

Comment: RedBean is full of awesome sauce.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that [Gacela](http://gacelaphp.com/documentation/usage/relationships-advanced/) can handle automatically fetching related information:

1) Inheritance relationship

In an example like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE wizards (
    wizardId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ROLE ENUM('teacher', 'student') NULL,
    addressId INT UNSIGNED NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_address_wizard
    FOREIGN KEY (addressId)
    REFERENCES addresses(addressId)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE = Innodb;

CREATE TABLE students (
    wizardId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    houseId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    isDAMembmer BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT fk_wizard_student
    FOREIGN KEY (wizardId)
    REFERENCES wizards(wizardId)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_house_students
    FOREIGN KEY (houseId)
    REFERENCES houses(houseId)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = Innodb;
```

The `students` table has the same primary key as the `wizards` table and because of the foreign key relationship definition, Gacela will detect that `students` inherits
all of the fields from `wizards`.

2) Dependent relationship

This is probably closer to what you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    addressId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    locationName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = Innodb;

CREATE TABLE wizards (
    wizardId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ROLE ENUM('teacher', 'student') NULL,
    addressId INT UNSIGNED NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_address_wizard
        FOREIGN KEY (addressId)
        REFERENCES addresses(addressId)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE = Innodb;
```

However, this example still differs slightly from your example because the addressId is in the `wizards` table thus creating a belongsTo relationship rather than a hasMany which is 
what your example reflects.

There is a third option available in Gacela, however I would first suggest that you consider that while it is often preferable to fetch data eagerly, there are real performance implications
in always fetching eagerly rather than lazy loading data. It is for this reason that Gacela (and basically every other Data Mapper or ORM) by default does not eagerly fetch data from hasMany relationships. 
That said, you could write something like the following:

```
class Mapper extends \Gacela\Mapper 
{

    public function find($id)
    {
        $query = $this->_source()->query();

        $query->from('persons', array('fullName'))
            ->join('phones', 'phones.person=persons.id', array('phonenumber'), 'left')
            ->where('persons.id = :id', array(':id' => $id);

        $data = $this->_source->query($query);

        return $this->_load($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noah. The last way is nice but need to know Gacela codes well that takes some time but may help me to develop it for my purposes.